# Java Sql GUI Error

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
// Button Update
private void jButton_UpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               



    String query = "UPDATE `petrol` SET `Available`="+jTextField_Id.getText()+" WHERE `Pump` = '"+jTextField_FirstName.getText();
   executeSQlQuery(query, "Updated");
}                                              


 // Button Delete
private void jButton_DeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    String query = "DELETE FROM `petrol` WHERE Pump = '"+jTextField_FirstName.getText();
     executeSQlQuery(query, "Deleted");
```

I get an error message regarding the syntax , i also have a try catch block

Comment: post the error message

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

There is some inconsistency with the values to the parameters in the SQL syntax. The value to *Available* is not enclosed in single quotes at all and the value to *Pump* only has one at the beginning (in both queries). The following queries would make more sense..

```
String query = "UPDATE `petrol` SET `Available`='"+jTextField_Id.getText()+"' WHERE `Pump` = '"+jTextField_FirstName.getText() + "'";
```

and

```
String query = "DELETE FROM `petrol` WHERE Pump = '"+jTextField_FirstName.getText() + "'";
```

(Also be aware of SQL injection with this kind of parameter insertion.)